# error shmat function when simulating MIPS file in Qemu

Tags: memory, qemu

I want to run (simulating) MIPS file with Qemu:

```
$file httpd
httpd: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0, no section header
```

`chroot` to `rootfs` and then run my file:
[image]

i found `oalShm_init` function into `libcms_core.so` library and decompile it with `ghidra`:

[image]

first `httpd` file use `shmget` for create shard memory and then use `shamt` for give access to this space;

but Qemu error in this function and can't mapping or can't run it

how to i can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the [man page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/ccompiler/doc750/html/lr2/z2101589.htm):

> The addr argument to shmat specifies a pointer value indicating the
> address at which the memory segment is to be attached. If addr is NULL
> , the segment will be attached at an address selected by the system.
> If addr is specified, shmat will fail if the segment cannot be
> attached as specified because memory is already allocated near the
> address specified

.

It seems the code expects 0x58800000 to be a valid address and it isn’t under QEMU.

You can try to either play with QEMU configuration to make it valid or patch the executable to use 0 instead so the address is determined by the system.